# Mercurial: Acl Extension Sample Of Preventing Web Access

Tags: iis, mercurial, access-control

I can see how you can use the Acl Extension to control the push/pull to a particular repository by certian users, but can you control "WEB" access to a repository using the Acl Extenstion?  I would like certain repositories to only show up for certain users.

I am deploying on IIS7, so the solution will need to work in that environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're doing this via the HGWeb CGI script.  If you are, you can specify `allow_push` and `allow_read` parameters in each project's `.hg/hgrc` file.  If you specify an `allow_read` other than `*`, users who are not in the list will not even see the project on the HGWeb project listing page.

Comment: How did you configure IIS so that a username is required from the client?

Answer (score 0):

Just use normal `.htaccess` like fonctionnality to restrict which repo are accessible. `hg` mostly doesn't care about auth and leaves that to the web server.

Comment: This is IIS7, I didn't think .htaccess would work in that environment.